# Sublime Text 3 API plugin for regex replacing text

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a small plugin in Sublime Text 3 to replace all empty lines. I used `re` module to do regex replace text. These are my codes test on console:

```
>>> text = 'abc \n\nOk'
>>> print(text)
abc 

Ok
>>> text = re.sub(r'^\n','',text)
>>> text
'abc \n\nOk'
```

I can search on ST3 by  `Ctrl+F = '^\n'`. Why does the pattern `^\n` not working in the plugin?

Comment: No, not at all lines have double `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't use **multiline flag** in your code. Try this:

```
re.sub(re.compile('^\n', re.MULTILINE), '', s)
```

Comment: oh, thank you! I have tested OK on console and plugin.